# Lowering error using pyDEM dem processor

Tags: python, gis, numba

Executing this script in Spyder :

```
import os
from pydem.dem_processing import DEMProcessor
filename__geotiff = 'D:\temp\CH_DTED_l0.tif'
if os.path.exists(filename__geotiff):
  dem_proc = DEMProcessor(filename__geotiff)
mag, aspect = dem_proc.calc_slopes_directions()
```

Gets me the following error :

> Failed at object (object mode backend)
>
> slc0.8
>
> File "........\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydem\dem_processing.py", line 2176
>
> [1] During: lowering "$1309 = call $1308(ang_adj, dX, dY, data, direction, facets, mag, shp, slc0.8)" at D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydem\dem_processing.py (2176)

I'm using `spyder` launched in an Anaconda virtual environment with `gdal`, `numba` and `pyDEM` installed.

Comment: this path `'D:\..\..\..\..\CH_DTED_l0.tif'` is VERY strange (unlikely to be the problem though). Better use raw prefix & absolute path or relative but not both...

Comment: It's not the real path. I'll edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: aaaah now we're in business... use raw suffix or your `'D:\temp\CH_DTED_l0.tif'` becomes `'D:\<tabulation char>emp\CH_DTED_l0.tif'`: ex: `r'D:\temp\CH_DTED_l0.tif'`

Comment: Same error with the raw suffix.

Comment: one less error! put XXXXX in the file path, you'll see it's the same. you don't even reach the file open part.