# PyDEM LoweringError: slc0.8

Tags: python, gis, numba

I'm in Win7 64, Anaconda Python installation, pip installed PyDEM.

I'm getting an error when calling `.calc_slopes_directions()` on a `DEMProcessor` instance (see below).

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510509/lowering-error-using-pydem-dem-processor); that seems not to be the same problem I have.

This `LoweringError: slc0.8` seems to be related to `Numba`.

This is the code I enter and the error I get:

```
from pydem.dem_processing import DEMProcessor

os.chdir(r'D:\my_path')

a_tile = r'31an2_clipped_wgs84.tif'

dem_proc = DEMProcessor(a_tile)

mag, aspect = dem_proc.calc_slopes_directions()
starting slope/direction calculation for chunk 1 [0:516, 0:516]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-6dc0db5771d2>", line 1, in <module>
    mag, aspect = dem_proc.calc_slopes_directions()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydem\dem_processing.py", line 853, in calc_slopes_directions
    self.dY[te:be-1])

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydem\dem_processing.py", line 879, in _slopes_directions
    return self._tarboton_slopes_directions(data, dX, dY)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydem\dem_processing.py", line 890, in _tarboton_slopes_directions
    self.facets, self.ang_adj)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 285, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 531, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 725, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 369, in compile_extra
    return self.compile_bytecode(bc, func_attr=self.func_attr)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 378, in compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_bytecode()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 690, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 677, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 257, in run
    raise patched_exception

LoweringError: slc0.8
```

Comment: Can you reproduce error with other .tif files, or on other OS/platforms?